# Rails: listing records from multiple tables in single chronological list

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 2 models: `task` and `request_task`.  They are different tables because they are very different items.

I also have a "My Tasks" portion of my application where I want to show a single list that combines both `tasks` and `request_tasks` ordered by `due_date`.

I see a few options, but I'm not sure which is the cleanest approach.  I'm trying to find a solution that is as simple as possible and follows most conventions.

## (1) Two DB queries and join/order in Ruby

This would work, but is slow and not performant, in my opinion.  I would rather use the power of a DB to select and order data instead of Ruby.  This list could potentially be a few hundred records.

```
# Pseudocode
tasks = current_user.tasks
request_tasks = current_user.request_tasks
sorted_records = (tasks + request_task).sort! { |a, b| a.due_date <=> b.due_date }
```

## (2) SQL Query to make one DB query

I would prefer something like this, but the issue is I don't know how to take the records and instantiate the proper model (`task` or `request_task`).  I'm also not very good at the SQL required for this:

```
class AbstractTask
  def records
    # Some ActiveRecord/SQL that selects filtered Tasks and RequestTasks from DB and instantiates proper model
  end
end

# Combines Tasks and RequestTasks that match criteria and are ordered
records = AbstractTask.records.where(user_id: current_user.id).order(:due_date)
```

## (3) Use Single-Table Inheritance to reduce to a single table

This "works", but then I'll have a bunch of unused attributes because `tasks` and `request_tasks` are pretty different.

But this has the benefit of being able to query a single table and return a list of all relevant records.

This may be the simplest approach at the moment.  I think it will give me everything I want, just with some unused attributes for half the records.  That trade-off may be worth it if there's no other clean solution.

Comment: A cleaner option would be polymorphism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804596/2697183

Comment: @AbM: thanks for the comment.  I reviewed the SO question as well as the Railscast referenced in that question.  But it looks like the solution presented there is to create another "abstract" table such as "my_tasks" that then references either a `task` or `request_task` object.  If I went that route, I think it would take a lot of DB queries to list each item's `title`, `assignee`, and `due_date`.  At that point I'm basically mimicking STI but with 3 tables instead of 1.  Am I misunderstanding what you were recommending?

Comment: You will have 3 tables with this approach but the idea is to put the common logic/attributes in one table, and then the different attributes in the other 2 tables respectively. Since in your index page you want to display both types of tasks, I am going to assuming that you will be displaying the attributes that are common to both, so therefore you would only need to query one table, and not 3.

Comment: @Dan L is there any relationship defined between `tasks` and `request_task` ?

Comment: @KetanDoshi: `tasks` and `request_tasks` do not have any relationship between them.  They are both "tasks", just different kinds.